# How to disable of press on button inside of gallery when I don't press on that in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

G'day!

I have a gallery with custom items in it:

Example of item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_width="253dp"
          android:layout_height="500dp"
          android:focusable="false">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/play"
    style="@style/somestyle" />
```

All items are showed by gallery fine, but when I try to scroll of gallery buttom inside of item which was pressed for scroll is pressed too. It'd be fine if I pressed on the button inside of item (what I didn't).

How can I turn off it?

Comment: add this in ur xml in image button android:clickable="false";

Comment: I need clickable button inside of item, but only I'm exactly to press on it (Right now I press on layout area (!NOT BUTTON !) and button is pressed)

Comment: Hmmm I guese I know where problem is =/ but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: ImageButton has state_pressed="true" and default settings. When I press on Layout button thinks that I pressed on it and shows me pressed state. I tried to add to this item state_focused=true, but it still doesn't work =/

Answer (score 0):

You should set a few more parameters to your `ImageButton` when using inside an item renderer, in order to make it respond to clicks (taps), but work as expected, without duplicating the parent's state:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/play"
    style="@style/somestyle"
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

This can be integrated into your `somestyle` definition.